# Is it possible to play Rockband Beatles on a Playstation 2?

Tags: rock-band, ps2

Is it possible to play Rockband Beatles on Playstation 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no PS2 version.  Source: [Everything](http://www.google.com/q=rock+band+beatles+ps2)